# prompt a series of 3 number in javascript

Tags: javascript, prompt

I am looking to create a function asking the user for how many numbers must be generated randomly in a series of 200 numbers i.e from 0 to 200.
THanks

Comment: Please do some research yourself before posting your question here. Try having a look here http://www.w3schools.com/ and see if you can solve it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is what you want:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click here</button>

  <ul id="list"></ul>

  <script>
    var RAND_MIN = 0;
    var RAND_MAX = 200;

    function randomInt(low, high) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low) + low);
    }

    function myFunction() {
      var answer = prompt("How many numbers must be generated randomly in a series of 200");

      if (answer != null) {
        var n = parseInt(answer, 10);
        var list = document.getElementById("list");

        for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          var li = document.createElement("li");

          li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(randomInt(RAND_MIN, RAND_MAX)));

          list.appendChild(li);
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```